# What are alchemy ingredients used for beyond the initial creation of a potion?

Tags: the-witcher-3

In the Witcher 3, there are alchemy ingredients littered all over the map. From the in game tutorials though, it states you only need to create a potion once, and then after that, when you meditate, alcohol will refill your potions automatically. So what am I supposed to do with all the extra alchemy ingredients?

Comment: I hope there is a real purpose for those. I really don't like the fact that I only need to brew a potion once.

Comment: You could always sell them for extra cash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [here](http://www.tentonhammer.com/guides/witcher-iii-wild-hunt/witcher-iii-alchemy-and-potion-guide)

> If you meditate **with hard alcohol**, then any potion, oil, or bomb
>   (basically most quick-action consumables) you've previously crafted
>   will refill. This doesn't work obviously for mutagens and components
>   Just be sure to meditate in a safe spot. Wine doesn't work, it has to
>   be hard liquor.
>
> If you craft a mutagen potion, it will forever refill in this way.
>   This is a direct response to Dragon Age: Inquisitions need to have you
>   gather herbs endlessly to keep making health potions. You only have to
>   craft a potion once.

Well there are tons and tons of diagrams for new potions so all those ingredients can go for those new potions. And now you need a lot more ingredients to make a potion so it isn't bad gathering ingredients.

If you don't need them go ahead and sell them for some extra orens.

Comment: In my opinion this makes alchemy too easy. When I want to go into battle I don't have to "prepare" e.g prepare potions any more. I just have to sit down for one our and I have all my potions ready. For me personally this takes a lot of fun from alchemy. Do you know if this is different in higher difficulties? Only played difficulty 2 so far.

Comment: in the guides there is no mention of difficulty. But basically you need alcohol and the potions will refill.

Comment: I think in the previous game you only really had to find herbs that matched one of 6 or so colors to use in potions, whereas in this game, ingredients are much more specific to craft. Anyways, good to know.